# Silverlight 4 Toolkit drag and drop on Mac (Safari)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

We have a silverlight drag and drop application which uses the toolkit (drag and drop happens from desktop into the browser and it uses a tree structure - which all works fine in windows), we need to have Mac support, we have created a simple application which uses a List Box as drop target just to test under Mac, without the toolkit it works fine as seen on the following thread with some minor modifications:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/180989/412444.aspx

Infact you can copy the javascript from the following source code, and it all works fine:

http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/silverlight/general/radupload-and-how-to-process-dropped-files-in-safari-under-mac.aspx

but we are using the silverlight toolkit and if include the toolkit ListBoxDragDropTarget such as:

nothing happens on the drop event.

Is there any way to fix this. Thanks in advance.